# iText7. How to flatten an existing pdf document

Tags: java, itext7

I have masked an existing pdf document with images, as described into this question: [iText7 Image Transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723093/itext7-image-transparency/57755895#57755895)

My issue is that somebody using Acrobat Reader DC Pro can still edit the document and remove the images, making the masking ineffective.

I have been thinking of flattening the pdDocument, but it seems the API applies to form, and not to the entire document. 
I have tried the code below, but it is still possible to edit the pdf and remove the masking images.

Do you have any advice for this?

```
// Read the pdf input
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(value);
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(outputStream);

PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter);
Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);
// Creating an ImageData object
ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.create(fileName);


for (int x = 1; x < 800; ) {
    for (int y = 1; y < 1000; ) {
        Image image = new Image(data);
        image.setFixedPosition(x , y);
        document.add(image);

        y = y + y1 + 40;
    }
    x = x + x1 + 40;
}
PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true).flattenFields();
// The content has now been modified, return it as a stream
document.close();
```

I expect: the image cannot be removed, or the document cannot be edited

Comment: Why not just set the PDF permissions? As an Adobe product, Acrobat will strictly respect those.

Comment: yes why not. How do you do that programmatically?

Comment: That's... something you could have just looked up in the itext API docs? But here, have a link: https://coderanch.com/how-to/javadoc/itext-2.1.7/com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfWriter.html#setEncryption(byte[],%20byte[],%20int,%20int) - keep the username and password null and then OR the permissions you do want to allow. Anything else will be forbidden at the document level. (For instance, even if you don't want people to edit, you probably still want `AllowFillIn`)

Comment: Have you looked at stamping properties ? and pass them to the new PdfDocument constructor.. https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/7.0.1/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/StampingProperties.html

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans *"That's... something you could have just looked up in the itext API docs? But here, have a link"* - While the OP indeed could simply have looked it up, a link to iText 2.1.7 JavaDocs are not *that* helpful for a user of iText 7...

Comment: fair point - I'm still assuming they know how to google, but permissions in itext7 use https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/7.0.2/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfEncryption.html

Comment: Honestly, if there is some good itext documentation on general purpose, if I am asking these questions it is because I can't find answers elsewhere. Reading a javadoc doesn't tell you how to do things