# Setting alpha in pdf

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to set the alpha value in a simple "Hello World" test program

This code will draw 3 test rectangles at 100% opacity

```
stream
0.9 0.5 0.0 rg                  'set color space to DeviceRGB and set color              
100 400 300 300 re f            'define rectangle and fill
q                               'save graphic state 
0.1 0.9 0.5 rg                  'set color space to DeviceRGB and set color
100 200 200 200 re f            'define rectangle and fill
Q                               'restore graphic state 
350 200 50 50 re f              'define rectangle and fill
endstream
```

I would like to do the same but set opacity values to 50% for the last 2 rectangles

```
stream
0.9 0.5 0.0 rg                  'set color space to DeviceRGB and set color              
100 400 300 300 re f            'define rectangle and fill
q                               'save graphic state 
0.1 0.9 0.5 rg                  'set color space to DeviceRGB and set color
0.5 CA                          'SET OPACITY TO 50%
100 200 200 200 re f            'define rectangle and fill
Q                               'restore graphic state 
350 200 50 50 re f              'define rectangle and fill
endstream
```

The **0.5 CA** does not work.

Any suggestions?

---

Edit:

OK so revised code to draw 3 overlapping rectangles
rect 1 Red (0% Transparent)
rect 2 Green (50% Transparent)
rect 3 Blue (75% transparent)
Transparency does not set, because I don't know how.

```
2 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Pages
  /MediaBox [ 0 0 350 350 ]
  /Count 1
  /Kids [ 3 0 R ]
>>
endobj

5 0 obj  % page content
<<
  /Length 44
>>
stream
1 0 0 rg
n
50 150 150 150 re
f
0 1 0 rg
n
100 100 150 150 re
f
0 0 1 rg
n
150 50 150 150 re
f
1 0 0 rg
n
0 g
endstream
endobj
```

Comment: *"The 0.5 CA does not work."* - Not really surprising as there is no **CA** instruction for PDFs. Instead create a graphics state dictionary with an entry with a **CA** *key* and reference that graphics state.

Comment: How do I create a graphics state dictionary?

Comment: *"How do I create a graphics state dictionary?"* - Well, any general-purpose PDF library brings along means to generate them. You don't tell us, though, how exactly you generate you PDFs, so how can we tell you how you create graphics state dictionaries?

Comment: I'm only seeing opaque rectangles, not transparent overlapping rectangles in the attachments.

Comment: The origins of the 2nd and 3rd rectangles were wrong in my first question .

Comment: I added revised code (in original question) to draw 3 overlapping rectangles.      The code draws them all opaque, but 2nd and 3rd rectangles should be transparent to let the rectangles underneath to show through.                                  I wanted to upload an image to show how they should look with transparency set, but can't figure out how to upload the PNG image.

Comment: @KJ I just saw what you did for me. I realized it wasn't an image you uploaded, but rather a pdf I could download and examine the underlying pdf code. THANKS!!! The rectangle underneath does not show through however, so I don't believe the transparency was in fact set.

Comment: Trying to add document as you did [link](https://docdro.id/qbHCP4v)

Comment: Trying to add PNG of what I would like PDF to look like [link](https://www.imagevenue.com/ME1702JV)

Comment: Similar question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484590/how-to-set-fill-alpha-in-pdf) but I still can't get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK this Answer
Is per @mkl 's comments and [their answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484590/how-to-set-fill-alpha-in-pdf) so I previously showed in comments you can be elaborate in adding a state, but it can be simply boiled down to this commented version. You need to decide what happens at that end red definition it will currently be 50% translucent.
[image]. Note the n you use between setting colour and applying to the rectangles is per @mkl unnecessary, so removed from answer.

```
%PDF-1.7

1 0 obj  % entry point
<<  /Type /Catalog  /Pages 2 0 R >>
endobj

2 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages  /MediaBox [ 0 0 350 350 ]  /Count 1  /Kids [ 3 0 R ] >>
endobj

% Add the graphics entry per the linked answer into resources add /CA for boundary
% e.g /Resources<</ExtGState<</GS1<</ca 0.5>>>>>>

3 0 obj
<< /Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<<
/ExtGState<</SeeThrough<</ca 0.5/CA 0.5>>>>
/Font<</F1 4 0 R>>
>>/Contents 5 0 R >>
endobj

4 0 obj
<< /Type/Font /Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Times-Roman>>
endobj

5 0 obj  % page content make it bigger while working
<</Length 351>>
stream
q
% red colour looks similar as solid
1 0 0 rg
%place 150 square 50 in 150 up and fill
50 150 150 150 re f

% green colour but we want a translucent graphics state
/SeeThrough gs
0 1 0 rg
100 100 150 150 re f

% blue colour but we want same translucent graphics state
0 0 1 rg
150 50 150 150 re f

%red colour unused
1 0 0 rg
0 g
Q

endstream
endobj

%Saved no problem but add new Xref

xref
0 6
0000000000 65536 f
0000000012 00000 n
0000000083 00000 n
0000000313 00000 n
0000000459 00000 n
0000000531 00000 n

trailer
<</Size 6/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
1022
%%EOF
```

**NOTE your source blue is 25% NOT 50%** thus you will need an extra state say
`/Paler<</ca .25/CA .25>>` and for good measure you could add `/Solid<</ca 1/CA 1>>`

NOTE I have used descriptive names, but the norm would be `/GS1` , `/GS2` , `/GS0` .

To get this
[image]

use

```
/ExtGState<</SeeThrough<</ca 0.5/CA 0.5>>/Paler<</ca 0.25/CA 0.25>>/Solid<</ca 1.0/CA 1.0>>>>
```

with

```
% blue colour but we want brighter translucent graphics state
/Paler gs
0 0 1 rg
150 50 150 150 re f
```

and

```
%red colour unused but revert to solid
/Solid gs
1 0 0 rg
150 150 50 50 re f
```

Later edit
<strike>At this point you should see that central solid red is not so solid!</strike> There was an human error on my part. The result should be as above.

Comment: There are a number or **n** instructions that are not needed, strictly speaking even invalid.

Comment: Thank you @KJ This is amazing for me!!!! Exactly what I wanted. I am going to fool now with adding the 25% GraphicsState for the Blue Rectangle and changing names to GS0,GS1,GS2 I am new to this forum, and not familiar with protocol - do I mark answer as resolved? If I have more questions later, can I come back to this thread and ask using comments?

Comment: OK thank you again @KJ. I "Accepted this answer" via tick mark, as all 3 rectangles now render with the transparency that they should. A new but separate problem arises, in that all my different fonts render as Arial. I will post a new question tomorrow.

Comment: Actually I was able to post new question today. Hoping this is an easy issue to resolve.